# How create calendar programmatically with source type local, iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, ekeventkit

I am creating a calendar from my application with EKSourceTypeLocal. I am able to create that calendar but when i goto ical and see the list of calendars it is not there. I used Eventkit framework to create custom calendar on iOS 5.0.

Please suggest me.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post some code? Also, how are you going about doing this?